# Civilization 6 turn timer for single player

Tags: civilization-6

Can you set a turn timer in **Single Player** in Civ 6, preferably in the Gathering Storms pack. All posts mention turn timer for multiplayer only.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you're trying to limit your own turn time, just use your phone's timer or whatever else you've got on hand. If you're trying to limit the AI's turn time, you can't.

Comment: Yes, I want to limit my own turn time. A phone timer works but I don't want to reset it after every turn. I was looking for an in-game timer as it would be enforced automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They haven't had single player turn timers in the Civilization series for a while now. Your only options for single player turn limiting is to set up the Score Victory or Turn Limit options.

Score Victory - At the end, highest score wins.

Turn Limit - After a set amount of turns 200, 250 (whatever), the game ends.

As you mentioned, turn timers exist in Multiplayer. **I'm not sure if this works, you'd have to test it**:

You could try to set up a multiplayer game privately, add a bunch of AI and yourself, and start the game without any other human players.

Comment: Turn timers exist basically so if one of the players afks, the game is not basically softlocked for the other players. Weird to use it in SP. But your solution might work.

Comment: Agreed that turn timers are weird for SP - the older Civ games used to have them to my understanding, but they got rid of them years ago for SP.